# Random key pressing continuously with a beep

Tags: ubuntu, boot, keyboard, motherboard

I have an old laptop, with 2 OS one Ubuntu 20.04 and another Windows Vista (shipped with the laptop) installed. A few days ago, when I booted up the machine into Ubuntu, I noticed a continuous key press of "<<<<<<" and a beep with every key press suddenly appearing when the OS was loading.

I am not sure but there seems to be some delay to boot up since then.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

From experience I had similar situation and that key was stuck basically, check your keyboard that has the < key of its stuck for some reasons try to remove it and cleaning below it (on ThinkPads are just pulling it slowly pls check your other vendors if its different brand to avoid breaking it)

Comment: I checked the keyboard and there's no key stuck. Basically my laptop keyboard doesnt work properly. When I connect external keyboard it works fine. But I cant get rid of this symbol appearing on my screen and hence unable to type in on the laptop

Comment: its definitely something stuck, if not the keys, its physically hardware